# Can't load javascript file in localhost using xampp

Tags: javascript, php, html, xampp, localhost

I am new at web development and I want to upload a main.js scrip in my PHP file but it gives me this error

[image]

I used a script tag to upload the js file like this:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="../assets/js/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Maybe there is some error in formatting in your JS file.

Comment: Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879671/only-on-firefox-loading-failed-for-the-script-with-source ad/script blocking w/ Firefox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be due to many things:

1. Check ad/script blocker
2. Check if the browser can load it from the view page source option
3. Try pasting it before all scripts call it could be due to some functions in previous scripts, I faced this issue before.
   This might help.

Comment: It works when I wrote in the script src  assets/js/main.js . I just removed the ../      I don't understand why it work? the script is in folder named inc so I wrote ../ to go back ,then enter assets folder to  my js file