# Loading failed for <scripts> node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, loading

I try to use my Room.js in my index.html on the client side of my Node.js server(v10.15.0 + express, socket.io).
I keep getting errors.
When I load it via script tags in the index.html file, the console gives me a

> Loading failed for "script" with .. "Room.js".
>    ReferenceError: Room is not defined

When I use require in the **[app.js](https://pastebin.com/g9hu97R3)** like this:

```
const roomObj = require("./client/js/Room.js");
const Room = new roomObj();
```

I only get this Error

> ReferenceError: Room is not defined

**[Room.js](https://pastebin.com/bpZsTCZJ)**

```
module.exports = Room;
function Room(name, o, obs, ep){
 this.name = name;
 this.o = o;
 this.obs = obs;
 this.getSth = function(ep){}
 this.loadRoom = function(){}
}
```

**[index.html](https://pastebin.com/5qVUBMq9)**

```
<script src="./js/Room.js"></script> 
<script>
 function loadRoom(){
   let room = new Room(name, o, obs, ep);
   room.loadRoom();
 }
</script>
```

**Update**

> Getting 404 Error for Room.js

When accessing localhost:2000/js/ and following subdirectories I got the

> Cannot GET /js/
>   and the same result for every other Path

**Solution:** (from Comments in answer)
replaced line 5-7 in app.js with

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));
```

Comment: Look at your network inspector and see if you are not getting a 404 error.

Comment: Is `Room.js` in the same directory as `index.html` on the web server? Do you use Webpack or other build tool?

Comment: Also, which browser do you use? If I try to reproduce your problem, I get `'module' is not defined` error.

Comment: @Imarqs Yes I get a 404 Error

Comment: @Filip I'm using firefox 65.0.1x64 and the paths are ./index.html and ./js/Room.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, check if `Room.js` is in the same directory as `index.html` on the web server. From your first error, it looks like the script file was not found.

If not, move them to the same directory or correct script tag in `inde.html`. If this won't work, see below for another possible solution.

**Update after comment:**

If JS file is in `./js/Room.js`, you need to point the script in HTML file to it.

```
<script src="./js/Room.js"></script> 
<script>
 function loadRoom(){
   let room = new Room(name, o, obs, ep);
   room.loadRoom();
 }
</script>
```

**Update after discussion:**

The server (Express) loaded `index.html` in root and `client` in the subdirectory of the web server.

You can remove lines 5-7 (from your link) and replace them
 with `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));`. This will load `client` to root of the web server.

Note that you would probably still get below error.

---

In the browsers, `module` is not defined, so `module.exports` would give the error and script will fail.

You should remove line `module.exports = Room;` from `Room.js` so the file will load correctly in the browser. But then it won't work in Node.js script, because function `Room` will not be exported from the file.

If you need to use the same file in Node.js and browser, I recommend you to use Gulp, Webpack, Browserify, Parcel or other web application bundler.

Comment: I had a typo in my script.src (edited it). Stil getting the same error and I need to load image data from Room.js to clientBrowser

Comment: @jje32dys Check if you get 404. If you get it, paths are probably wrong or there is some other HTTP error. Try to manually open your `Room.js` file in the browser and check if it loads. Also, try to test this in another browser.

Comment: That's probably it but the paths are the same as I mentioned. What could be the problem?

Comment: Try to open script directly in the browser. Maybe path is not correctly resolved in HTML file. Also, try to use another browser. There was some similar error (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879671/only-on-firefox-loading-failed-for-the-script-with-source) in Firefox with ad blockers. The problem may also be with the SSL certificate. Check if answers in linked question work for you.

Comment: Can you provide the exact errors in console and network inspector (maybe some screenshots). Also, if possible post URL to your server so I can look what happens.

Comment: My node server is only hosted locally. I tried started FF in safe mode and Chrome and got the same results. Screenshot of error: http://666kb.com/i/e1epb4gdb7il5d8j9.png

Comment: What if you access script directly (`http://localhost:2000/js/Room.js`)? Also, try to load the just folder of scripts (`http://localhost:2000/js/`) and try to locate the *actual* location of the script.

Comment: I get "Cannot GET /js/room" and "Cannot GET /js/"

Comment: So server probably doesn't host your JS files in that location? Try to find the location with guessing. Maybe it is `client/js/Room.js`, `Room.js` or similar.

What server do you use? Maybe it is configured to only host `client/index.html` and not whole directory. Try to access other files that should exist in the server.

Comment: I'm using Node.js and you are right, I get the same error for all other files

Comment: So the server is configured to only host `client/index.html`. I don't know what exact Node.js server do you use (there are many), but you should point it to `client/` (whole directory).

Comment: I'm using Node v10.15.0 with Express and Socket.io

Comment: Do you start that server with `node app.js`? If so, there should be some line like `app.use(express.static('client/index.html'))` in `app.js`. Replace that line with `app.use(express.static('client'))`. If this will work, I will update my answer and provide more details about this in it.

Comment: I've changed that but than I get the error message when connection to localhost:2000 . I provided links to my app.js room.js and index.html in my question

Comment: You should remove lines 5-7 (from your link) and replace them with `app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/client"));`. This should load add files in `client` directory.