# sourced javascript file loads in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a script that loads fine in Chrome, but not FireFox or IE. I get an

`error console messages loading failed for the <script> "http://myfile.js"` . however, if I copy/paste the script reference into the browser url, it loads up

when i copy and paste the functions from that file into the html document that I am loading. it seems to work. but it's a dirty hack

`<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="/agents/repeater_stats.js?rand=<%= rand(5000) %>"></script>`

Comment: Did you try hard refresh? (CTRL + F5) Sounds and looks like a problem with your cache.

Comment: Have you tried this? [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46469460/11316791)

Comment: Note that the `language` attribute is [obsolete](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/obsolete.html#obsolete)

Comment: Yes, thank you. Don't know what the equivalent keyboard shortcut is on Mac, however, in history, i cleared all cache and cookies. still the same, thanks

Comment: disabled the ad blocker and it worked in firefox. thanks itsnesky ! But what could be in this script to trigger an add blocker? Also, what can I do in Edge or IE to fix it? still broken there. but kinda different errors. simicolon missing, etc