# How to deal with Firefox add-on that breaks my site for users?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I have an email subscription form on my site so users can sign up for a newsletter. This uses a script generated by my email campaign provider (GoDaddy), which consists of a form that posts to a certain endpoint on their site, not mine.

For some users, including me, this is causing the "Loading failed for the script" error on Firefox. This is discussed in detail in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879671/only-on-firefox-loading-failed-for-the-script-with-source) and the answers all involve finding and disabling the add-on that's causing the problem.

And indeed, on my machine, the "DuckDuckGo Privacy Essentials" add-on was the culprit, and when I disabled it, the form post works correctly.

**But I need to be able to make this work for my users, not just me.** If someone tries to subscribe and gets a silent failure, they'll just not care that much. Even if I could detect what happened, I can't expect the average user to start disabling add-ons just to be able to subscribe.

So how can this problem be fixed properly so it just works?

Comment: This is a tough question. Ideally, GoDaddy will fix their script to work with the privacy essentials. It *seems* (at least to the addon) that the script is doing something potentially dodgy. However, we don't live in a perfect world. The best compromise I can think of is try to detect the failure and show an error message to the users saying "this was blocked by an addon". People using addons like the Privacy Essentials *should* be more computer literate and be able to disable the addon or at least use a different browser. Not sure if you can actually do anything yourself.

Comment: Is there any way to know what seems dodgy so that I could maybe tweak the script so that it doesn't do that? I had the idea to change the script so it posts back to my site, and I would relay it to GoDaddy, and then relay success back to the script. Annoying, but possible. But I don't want to do all that work without knowing what the add-on is objecting to in the first place.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know. I'm mostly just aware of the Privacy Essentials addon, I don't know if you can extract debug or operational information of some sort from it, so you can see its reasoning. I suppose you can read the source and try to debug it - the addon should be open source.