# Django cookie banner: window.wpcc undefined

Tags: javascript, html, django, cookies

On my GitHub pages website, I have been using https://www.websitepolicies.com/ to create a simple cookie consent banner.
Trying to use the same snipped in my new Django app does not work however.

The HTML code for the banner goes into the HTML head and looks like

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.wpcc.io/lib/1.0.2/cookieconsent.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.wpcc.io/lib/1.0.2/cookieconsent.min.js" defer></script>
<script>window.addEventListener("load", function(){window.wpcc.init({"border":"thin","corners":"small","colors":{"popup":{"background":"#f6f6f6","text":"#000000","border":"#555555"},"button":{"background":"#555555","text":"#ffffff"}},"position":"bottom","transparency":"10","content":{"href":"https://www.websitepolicies.com/policies/view/<hashcode_to_my_policy>"}})});</script>
```

Adding this to the head of `base.html` inside my Django app doesn't work.
No banner is displayed and instead, the console logs the error:

```
Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://wpcc.io/lib/1.0.2/cookieconsent.min.js”.
Uncaught TypeError: window.wpcc is undefined
```

Why is the snipped working fine with my GitHub pages site but not with my Django app?
Why can `http://wpcc.io/lib/1.0.2/cookieconsent.min.js` not be loaded? If I copy it into the address bar, it loads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this had nothing to do with Django nor with the cookie banner per se. It seems like loading the script was simply blocked by my AdBlocker on Firefox: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46469460/2745116

Disabling the AdBlocker solved the problem.