# Failed to load livewire js assets on production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire-3

I've deployed my laravel 10 - livewire 3 apps on local server (office LAN server) but it seems the js assets of livewire did't loaded properly :

> Loading failed for the  with source
> “http://10.62.230.18:81/livewire/livewire.js?id=e2b302e9”.

This is my config file of asset url :

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://10.62.230.18:81'),
'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', 'http://10.62.230.18:81'),
```

This is my layout page which load the livewire's assets :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>{{ $title ?? 'WIP' }}</title>

        @vite('resources/css/app.css')
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ $slot }}

        @stack('scripts')
    </body>
</html>
```

I tried solutions [this](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/242) solution, however it didn't work for me because there is no publishable assets for livewire:assets

How to solve this issue ?

Comment: Try to publish the Livewire assets manually. This can be done by running the following command in your Laravel project: php artisan livewire:publish --assets

Comment: @KarlHill already tried, and it says that there is no publishable resource

Comment: Did you try running: php artisan config:clear?

Comment: @KarlHill yes and still got the same result

Comment: Bummer. You could always try running: 'php artisan vendor:publish --tag=livewire:assets --force' but it sounds like you'll still get the same result.

Comment: @KarlHill, exactly, it seems the livewire's assets couldn't be found

Comment: have you also tried with the method shown in the last comment (dec 19 2023) at the link you posted?

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45879671/only-on-firefox-loading-failed-for-the-script-with-source) seems that something that is blocking the request.. or try add this `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests">` to pass.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into similar issues with livewire.

When livewire assets haven't loaded for me it's usually due to a difference between a local environment and the production environment.

I've always solved it by explicitly defining the assets in the the blade layout file. In your case I would try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <title>{{ $title ?? 'WIP' }}</title>

        @vite('resources/css/app.css')
        @livewireStyles
    </head>
    <body>
        {{ $slot }}

        @livewireScripts
        @stack('scripts')
    </body>
</html>
```

I would also suggest that you run `composer update` from command line after you deploy.

Also you may have cache files that were deployed unintentionally.
To resolve that try removing the cache files by running

```
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan view:clear
```

If all else fails, then it is likely a permissions issue with the `/livewire/livewire.js` and/or `/livewire/livewire.css` files. (i.e. the permissions are too strict)

Lastly, if you're building from Alpine, there are other troubleshooting options. Since I dont work with alpine the best resource I can provide is the official docs: https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/installation#manually-bundling-livewire-and-alpine

Comment: already did but didn't worked for my case,
i tried this https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/242#issuecomment-1862093389 and it solved the problem

Comment: @owf.... glad you solved it... good to know that's a potential issue with nginx.. thx for the link to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try reference the livewire assests from AppServiceProvider.php

```php
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Livewire\Livewire;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Livewire::setScriptRoute(function ($handle) {
            return \Route::get('/vendor/livewire/livewire.js', $handle);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: already did but didn't worked for my case, i tried this github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/242#issuecomment-1862093389 and it solved the problem